# How to save customer custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have successfully installed new custom attribute via install schema during extension in existing customer entity.

My issue is whenever I tried to save customer, it gives me the error below.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 236

I am trying to save customer attribute via below code:

```php
$customerData[\Magento\Framework\Api\CustomAttributesDataInterface::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES] = [\Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeInterface::ATTRIBUTE_CODE=>'md_customer_profile_id',\Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeInterface::VALUE=>$customerProfileId];
$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray($customerObject, $customerData, '\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface');
$this->customerRepository->save($customerObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I write to custom attributes for customers.

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;

$this->objectManager = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER)->getObjectManager();
$this->customerRepo = $this->objectManager->create(CustomerRepositoryInterface::class);

/** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
$customer = $factory->create();

// Create new Customer
$factory = $this->objectManager->create(CustomerInterfaceFactory::class);

// Set custom attribute
$customer->setCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute_customer_profile_id', '123abc');


$this->customerRepo->save($customer);
```